# Get 2nd and 7th word following a specific word in PHP

Tags: php, string, search, preg-match

What I'd like to do is extract two values after a specific word using PHP.
This is an example link for the type of content I'm using: http://weather.uwyo.edu/cgi-bin/sounding?region=europe&TYPE=TEXT%3ALIST&YEAR=2020&MONTH=10&FROM=3112&STNM=16320

I would like to extract the TEMP and SKNT values for PRES = 850.0 hPa and echo them.
They're always the 2nd and 7th values following 850.0 in the first column, but the number of spaces between the values and the digits themselves can change.
Furthermore 850.0 is not always the 16th row.

Can you help me? Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is a var `TYPE=TEXT%3ALIST` in that URL, better to research if you can get JSON or something easier to work with.

Comment: We can help, we can't do it for you.  Show us your work and specifically which bit is going wrong and we will

Comment: Get the text in `<pre>` tags. Explode by newline into separate lines. Remove header. Iterate lines, split each line with `preg_split('~\s+~', $line)` into separate fields. Assign to array using hPa as index key. You can then access any given hPa's fields with e.g. `$data['850.0']`, and specific fields as `$data['850.0'][2]` etc. See how that works, and update your question with your effort to implement this.

Comment: If you don't care about the entire index, use `preg_match('~^\s*850.0\s+(.+)~m', $data, $match);` on the raw data and operate on that line only with `preg_split` as above. Otherwise, craft the regex to capture each field from the outset and get the `$match` indexes corresponding with desired fields/capture groups. Happy experimenting. Manual is your friend, see [`preg_match`](https://www.php.net/preg_match) for starters.